# XML Data and SQL Bulk Copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have XML Data that I am inserting into a SQL Table

```
  <data>
    <racedata>
      <race>1</race>
      <todays_cls>97</todays_cls>
    </racedata>
    <stats_data>
      <stat type="ALL_WEATHR">
        <starts>0</starts>
        <wins>0</wins>
        <places>0</places>
        <shows>0</shows>
        <earnings>0.00</earnings>
        <paid>0.00</paid>
        <roi />
      </stat>
      <stat type="AT_DST_CRS">
        <starts>13</starts>
        <wins>4</wins>
        <places>1</places>
        <shows>0</shows>
        <earnings>93448.00</earnings>
        <paid>12.00</paid>
        <roi>23</roi>
      </stat>
    </stats_data>
  </data>
```

The racedata inserts fine using SQLBulkCopy. As an example:

```
bc.DestinationTableName = "racedata";
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("race", "race");
bc.ColumnMappings.Add("todays_cls", "todays_cls");
```

The issue is when I try to insert the stats_data. When I try to capture the different stat categories like ALL_WEATHR and AT_DST_CRS, I get an error message because the data source and the target table columns have to have the same name. However, ALL_WEATHR and AT_DST_CRS are not column names, they are values. They tell how may wins, places, shows, etc on each type of surface.  How would I go about inserting them into a SQL Table?

Comment: Start by making a diagram of you database.  Every object in SQL is part of a table.  Some tables are going to be two columns with a name like ALL_WEATHR and a value like 0 and then another row with a name AT_DST_CRS and a value 13.  Other tables are going to are going to have 5 or 6 columns where all the rows have the same data in each column.

Comment: Please explain some more. Why would I have those two entries as columns when they are values? The data would not make sense.

Comment: Two column tables often exist where on is a name and the other a value.  We often use tables like this to contain and ID number and the and name associated with the ID.  Then we have other tables that use the ID number.  In other cases we have the same database on multiple servers and the two column tables would have the ServerName = SERVER123, the StartDate = 1/1/16, EndDate = 1/15/16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest was to pass the XML into a SQL Server Stored Procedure and shred it there with this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<data>
  <racedata>
    <race>1</race>
    <todays_cls>97</todays_cls>
  </racedata>
  <stats_data>
    <stat type="ALL_WEATHR">
      <starts>0</starts>
      <wins>0</wins>
      <places>0</places>
      <shows>0</shows>
      <earnings>0.00</earnings>
      <paid>0.00</paid>
      <roi />
    </stat>
    <stat type="AT_DST_CRS">
      <starts>13</starts>
      <wins>4</wins>
      <places>1</places>
      <shows>0</shows>
      <earnings>93448.00</earnings>
      <paid>12.00</paid>
      <roi>23</roi>
    </stat>
  </stats_data>
</data>';

SELECT RD.value('race[1]','int') AS Race_ID
      ,RD.value('todays_cls[1]','int') AS Race_todays_cls    
      ,ST.value('@type','varchar(max)') AS Stat_type
      ,ST.value('(./starts)[1]','int') AS Stat_starts
      ,ST.value('(./wins)[1]','int') AS Stat_wins
      ,ST.value('(./places)[1]','int') AS Stat_places
      ,ST.value('(./shows)[1]','int') AS Stat_shows
      ,ST.value('(./earnings)[1]','decimal(10,2)') AS Stat_earnings
      ,ST.value('(./paid)[1]','decimal(10,2)') AS Stat_paid
      ,ST.value('(./roi)[1]','int') AS Stat_roi
FROM @xml.nodes('data') AS A(DT)
CROSS APPLY DT.nodes('racedata') AS B(RD)
CROSS APPLY DT.nodes('stats_data/stat') AS C(ST)
```

Within the SP it is easy to store the values from table-like data in one - or better: in many related - table(s)

The result

```
+---------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
| Race_ID | Race_todays_cls | Stat_type  | Stat_starts | Stat_wins | Stat_places | Stat_shows | Stat_earnings | Stat_paid | Stat_roi |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
| 1       | 97              | ALL_WEATHR | 0           | 0         | 0           | 0          | 0.00          | 0.00      | 0        |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
| 1       | 97              | AT_DST_CRS | 13          | 4         | 1           | 0          | 93448.00      | 12.00     | 23       |
+---------+-----------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
```